# How to optimize database hits on integration specs?

Tags: rspec, automated-tests, integration-testing, rspec-rails

I have some actions in my application that results on multiple inserts, deletes and updates in database.

Today I test it in this way:

```
describe Checkout do
  # Many lets and a before block are placed
  # to create the context to my specs

  it "creates the items" do
    Checkout.call(params)
    expect(Item.count).to eq(3)
  end

  it "set the invoice due date" do
    Checkout.call(params)
    expect(Invoices.last.due_date).to eq("2015-09-15".to_date)
  end

  # ... many other tests checking the database
end
```

The problem is for each "it" the many and heavy "let" and "before" blocks are executed.

I want to prepare the context and check many things without lose the advantage of describe those tests in a natural language, or at least any suggestions to make things better.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: It's tough

1)
RSpec works very hard to make sure that test-data doesn't leak from one spec to another.  If it didn't we would have very difficult to debug issues in our tests.

2) 
We want to have clearly defined specs.  This gives us good and simple feedback on failure and serve as living documentation for the system.  This often means we have only one assertion per unit-test.

In unit-tests especially, you can speed things up by stubbing and mocking as much as possible.  Don't spin up a whole bunch of records when a Hash will work just as well.  Look into rspec-mocks, rr or other stubbing gems.

If you're using factory-girl there are times when you can use `FactoryGirl.build_stubbed` or `FactoryGirl.build` instead of saving records with `FactoryGirl.create`.  Also `attributes_for` can be really useful in functional and controller specs as it'll give you a hash of properties without creating a db object.

In your spec I notice that you're testing `Checkout` but making your assertions on other players (Invoices, Items).  These tests are testing more than just Checkout.  It might be possible for you to stub some of that out and speed up your tests.

For example:
Instead of verifying that a Checkout creates a new Invoice that has the right date verify that it simply sent the right message to Invoice:

```
it "sets the invoice due date" do
  expect(Invoices).to receive(:new).with({due_date: '2015-09-15'.to_date})
  Checkout.call(params)
end
```

However, this in itself is tricky and it's easy to find yourself testing too much implementation rather than behavior.  (ex. We wanted an Invoices, and it doesn't matter if it's created by .new, .generate, .build_invoices! etc)

You specifically mentioned *integration-testing*:

Integration tests have an additional disadvantage in that they have to go through the whole system and often require many database records, so they can be quite slow.  1 & 2 above pretty clearly block us here.

For integration tests I suggest relaxing #2 (above).  Don't be afraid to make multiple assertions in integration tests.  They're supposed to be from the user's point-of-view and a user would do more than one thing.

**In the end, you just have to find a balance.**

One thing you could consider doing, especially in integration tests, is to add stories to your specs in order to make them a little more expressive:

```
RSpec.feature "Courses",
  %q{
    As a student,
    I want to edit a listing of courses I'm involved in
    So that I can change my schedule
  },
  :js do
```

To be honest, integration tests are an area where I find the long setup time particularly bothersome and I wish there was a better way to have multiple tests share the same setup.  I've gone so far as to try to disable database cleaning for a set of specs (i.e. hack).

I would love it if someone else here can offer a better answer to this specific problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I already clean my specs avoiding all database hits as you suggestioned above. But as is an integration spec, The action causea a lot of colateral effects, and it is what I want to test. The mock approach does not will give to me the confidence what I expect.

Comment: Database hits just make the problem more apparent. But think about the rails controle, this layer have many colateral effects. If you want to test them you have to run the action for each colateral effects you want to test. I miss a way to run something once and be able to test as many side effects as I want.